# How can I get the exact time of each zodiac every year?

Tags: observational-astronomy, zodiac

I want to make a calculator for Chinese New Year calendar. There is a rule that a leap year happens if the eclipse happens before each zongqi (equivalent to the middle of zodiac sign, ie. 15º, 45º, 75º, 115º... to the sun).

Where is a good reference to know that the exact time of the earth entering each zodiac sign every year?

Comment: What have you looked at so far? I know  most astrological sites will tell you when the Sun enters each house, but those are 30 degree intervals. I assume some sites will give you "halfway" points too. You might look at https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues/273 or google/wikipedia the Chinese calendar for more information

Comment: @barrycarter I think [houses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_(astrology)) are more closely related to hour angle.

Comment: @MikeG OK, but https://astrostyle.com/learn-astrology/the-12-zodiac-houses/ suggests these are zodiac constellations too?

Comment: @barrycarter That's good insight. i don't do python. but i found something available in c#

Comment: @barrycarter Signs may influence houses in some astrological traditions, but I think they are aligned in the sky only when ♈︎ is on the eastern horizon (18h sidereal time).

Comment: @MikeG OK, so you're saying the sun's "house" is dependent on your location on Earth?

Comment: @barrycarter Yes, and the time of day.

Comment: @TrioCheung An answer outlining your C# solution would be of interest. In Python skyfield.almanac_east_asia.[solar_terms](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/almanac.html#solar-terms) might do the job.